# Assigning array values to ints and random array not generating (java)

Tags: java, arrays, int

I am trying to create three different random numbers from 0-3 and assign each to an `int` variable. How do I do this? Also, the array will not generate when `.opset` is `(0, 2)` but it will when it is `(1, 3)`. How can I fix this?

```
package varselect;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class varselect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] ints = new Random().opset(0, 2).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `opset()`?

Comment: There is no method named `opset` in class `java.util.Random`. Where did you get that from?

Comment: I checked the Javadocs for Java 11 and unless there is a newer version of Java I'm not aware of, I don't see what `opset` is.

Comment: And for your own perusal of **documentation**, Java 11 javadoc for `java.util.Random` is here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method named `opset` in class `java.util.Random`, so the code in your question does not compile. You can use the method [`ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#ints(int,int)) instead:

```
final int[] ints = new Random().ints(0, 4).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

Note that `ints` takes the lower bound (inclusive) and upper bound (exclusive) of the range in which you want to generate numbers, so if you want numbers between 0 and 3 inclusive then you need to specify `(0, 4)` as the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the correct way to do it:

```
final int[] ints = new Random().ints(0, 4).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
```

It uses `ints(0, 4)` which provides an `IntStream` with values from `0-3`, we then call `.distinct()` to get distinct values, `limit(3)` to get `3` distinct values and lastly we turn it into an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your result random integer array of length array 3 then you should pass bound parameter as 3 to Random.ints(int randomNumberOrigin, int randomNumberBound).

```
int[] randomIntArray = new Random().ints(0, 4).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
```

Comment: Like @Jesper said, `.ints(0, 3`) will generate values from `0-2` and *not* `0-3` like @BoldWarrior wants.

Comment: public IntStream ints(int randomNumberOrigin,
                      int randomNumberBound)
Returns an effectively unlimited stream of pseudorandom int values, each conforming to the given origin (inclusive) and bound (exclusive). --- This is the method description of ints() method. Bound parameter is exclusive here. So if we give 3 as bound parameter then it will random values from 0 to 2.

Comment: Yes I know, but the question stated `random numbers from 0-3`, so `randomNumberBound` should be `4`, not `3`.

Comment: Sorry my bad I thought it's from 0 to 2. Thanks for correcting me